How to error/exit a read operation that is blocked on a socket where there is no data
on some operating systems, when a socket is closed, the read operation errors, but on BSD it doesn't. This simple code works differently on different OS
import socket
import threading
# Function to handle reading from the socket
def read_from_socket(sock):
    while True:
        try:
            data = sock.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                continue
            print(f"Received data: {data}")
        except socket.error as e:
            print(f"Socket error: {e}")
            break
    print("Read thread exiting")
# Create a socket and connect to a server
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('example.com', 80))
print ("connected to socket")
# Start the read thread
read_thread = threading.Thread(target=read_from_socket, args=(sock,))
read_thread.start()
# Close the socket after some time
import time
time.sleep(20)
print ("closing the socket")
sock.close()
print ("closed the socket")
# Join the read thread to wait for its completion
read_thread.join()
print("Main thread exiting")

what are the ways we can exit the read thread on BSD

If true, this just looks like a bug to me. Certainly, in BSD, when a socket is closed locally, a blocking read on that socket should return immediately with an error indication. I'd like to see someone else reproduce this.

Similar thread: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/uTsVAkDLINI
